# Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY is not working with android 2.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I'm using the v7 support library.

When I'm trying to add the following lines Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY it is not reflecting on android version 2.3

Comment: That window feature would not have existed prior to Android 3.0, and there is no action bar in the `support-v4` library. I do not remember off the top of my head if the AppCompat or ActionBarSherlock action bar backports support overlay mode.

Comment: sorry.by mistake i write support v4, its support v7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  AppCompatActivity,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

does not work. Instead, use:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you using

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`

instead of

`supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`

?

Comment: supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In case your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, using:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

or:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

will not work. You need to use:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```